# Put buttons with Equal margins on both left and right side in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am new to Android. I want to put 4 buttons horizontally with equal margins with both left and right side as shown in the wire-frame diagram below:

[image]

I searched a lot on Google and Stackoverflow also. I tried to set **android:layout_weight="1"** . But it only sets equal margin from left-side. I want to set it on both sides and on multiple screen layouts. I want to know which layout and properties should be applied for this. I am using in Android studio and mostly used Drag-Drop method for design.

Currently I've XML layout as follows:

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="buttonThree"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="0dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="buttonFive"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="buttonSeven"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="0dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="buttonNine"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look at concept of `layout_weight` of `LinearLayout`

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, `layout_weight` will work with `LinearLayout`

Comment: Must have to Learn : [Android Layout Tricks](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: Donot downvote his Question , he is trying to learn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Layout weight works with LinearLayout, each view in linearlayout will take designeatedweight/weightsum times total width or height.

Move your buttons into linear layout with weight sum to 4. Assigning weight of buttons to 1 will make them take 1/4 th of screen space automatically. 
For equal spacing allocating margin to linear layout will make them look equally spaced.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="buttonThree"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="buttonFive"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="buttonSeven"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="buttonNine"
        android:text="9" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

that's right to set android:layout_weight="1" ,but only Linearlylayout effective,so you can

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="B1"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="B2"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="B3"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="B4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no space in between buttons. He wants same space.

Answer (score 4):

try out this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


</LinearLayout>
```

it will look something like this.

[image]

Comment: It will make space 10 10 dp in between buttons.

Comment: yes, but you can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

```
       <LinearLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="3"
        >

<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        ...
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        ...
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```